# C# casting generic class with an interface as placeholder

Tags: c#, generics, interface, casting

I have the following classes/interfaces:

```
public interface IConvexPolygon<T> where T : IPositionable
{
    IEnumerable<FPVector2> UniqueAxes { get; }
    IEnumerable<T> CornerPositionsClockwise { get; }
}
public class ConvexPolygon<T> : ConvexShape, IConvexPolygon<T> where T : IPositionable
{
...
}
public struct Positionable : IPositionable
{
...
}
```

I now want to cast a `ConvexPolygon<Positionable>` to `IConvexPolygon<IPositionable>` to be able to use its getters. This throws an invalid cast exception. I tried specifying covariance with `out` in the IConvexPolygon interface, with the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variance is applied only to references types, see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance):

> - Variance applies only to reference types; if you specify a value type for a variant type parameter, that type parameter is invariant for the resulting constructed type.

So you will need to change `Positionable` from struct to class, to make this cast work.

Also if you are planning to work `Positionable` via interface take in account that it [will be boxed](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBLANgHwAEAmARgFgAoQgZgAIS6BhOgbyrs4fsJToFkAFAEo2HLhIAKEAM7YM2CADsAhsFww6ABzoBeOkpgB3OtLkLlajSIDcVAJASAkmfmLV6zdiUYYUAGYqYDCSetp2lBIShKQAnILevgFBIcIREgC+4py0dDIYUACuYBimsm6WnnQgdC7lFh4arFmRXLmJfoHBta4NVjDNVBlAA==).